# DOM Methods get the right element from a Node - Using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am doing an exercise, but I am stuck. I need to get the first line of each paragraph after each "H4", but at the moment it is getting all the "P" from the first "H4".

I got an HTML and a JavaScript, the idea is to get a news summary after **Bizarre News Summary**, I have created the 'UL', 'LI' and appended them

```js
function newsSnippets() {
  let classNewsarticle = document.getElementsByClassName("newsarticle"); // Get classes by name 'newsarticle'
  let headlinesId = document.getElementById("headlines"); // Get Id 'headlines'
  let newsSummary = document.createElement("div"); // Create DIV
  headlinesId.appendChild(newsSummary); // Append headlines to DIV
  let newsSummaryList = document.createElement("ul"); // Create UL
  newsSummary.appendChild(newsSummaryList); // Append UL to DIV
  console.log(classNewsarticle);

  for (let i = 0; i < classNewsarticle.length; i++) {
    let newsSummaryListItem = document.createElement("LI"); // Create an LI for each H4
    newsSummaryList.appendChild(newsSummaryListItem); // Append the LI to the UL
    let getH4 = document.getElementsByTagName("H4")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    let getH4Node = document.createTextNode(getH4);
    let ellipsis = document.createTextNode(" . . . ");
    let p = document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].innerHTML;
    let pNode = document.createTextNode(p);
    newsSummaryListItem.appendChild(getH4Node) + // Append the texts node to the LI element
      newsSummaryListItem.appendChild(ellipsis) +
      newsSummaryListItem.appendChild(pNode);
    let newsList = document.createElement("LI"); // Create the inline text anchor

    document.body.insertBefore(newsList, newsSnippets[i]); // Insert the text anchor before headings  
  }
}

window.onload = newsSnippets;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
  <script src="scripts/fma_t1.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrappermain">
    <h1>Bizarre News Mash Up</h1>
    <section id="headlines">
      <h2>Bizarre News Summary</h2>
    </section>
    <section id="news">
      <h3>News Stories in Full</h3>
      <article class="newsarticle">
        <h4>What a load of Bull!</h4>
        <p>Chinese Kung Fu Masters are seeking the ultimate opponents</p>
        <p>Several times a week, kung fu teacher Ren Ruzhi enters a ring to spar with a bovine opponent around five times his weight and capable of killing him.</p>
        <p>Ren’s mixing of martial arts and bullfighting worries his mother, but the 24-year-old has never been hurt. Besides, he says, grappling with a snorting bull is exciting.</p>
        <p>It symbolizes the bravery of a man,” Ren told Reuters in Jiaxing in China’s eastern province of Zhejiang.</P>
      </article>
      <article class="newsarticle">
        <h4>Has Anybody got a Tissue?</h4>
        <p>A Hawaiian monk seal got an eel caught in its nose ― and it wasn’t the first time for these endangered creatures.</p>
        <p>The Hawaiian Monk Seal Research Program posted a startling pic of the poor pup on Monday, and the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration Fisheries provided more details in a post on Wednesday.</p>
      </article>
      <article class="newsarticle">
        <h4>Dog Pulls Off Spectacular Save During Argentina Soccer Match</h4>
        <p>A pooch invaded the pitch during a Federal A league match between Juventud Unida and Defensores de Belgrano over the weekend.</p>
        <p>Juventud Unida were already comfortably ahead against Defensores de Belgrano in their league clash when the dog made his unexpected cameo.</p>
      </article>
      <article class="newsarticle">
        <h4>Nobody Beats The Laws of Nature</h4>
        <p>A 69-year-old Dutch man has failed in his attempt to legally declare himself 20 years younger.</p>
        <p>Last month, motivational speaker Emile Ratelband filed a lawsuit against the Dutch government requesting that his date of birth be switched from March 11, 1949, to March 11, 1969.</p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!-- Stories from Huffington Post. Used for Teaching purposes -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the markup that this code is traversing? Ideally, combine it with the above code into an [mcve] so the community can clearly understand the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a little too complicated. If you are allowed to, try something like this:

```
function newsSnippets() {  
  const results = document.evaluate('//article[@class="newsarticle"]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  let temp = "<div><ul>"  
  for (let i = 0; i < results.snapshotLength; i++) {
    let node = results.snapshotItem(i);
    let new_item = "<li>"+node.querySelector('h4').innerText+ '...' +node.querySelector('p').innerText+"</li>";
    temp += new_item;
  }
temp += "</ul></div>"
let target = document.querySelector('section#headlines');  
target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', temp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jack for your help, the code above works perfectly. Although as a beginner I really do not understand some parts of your code. I going to save yours, but still I going to find a way to get what I want for the one I am working on.

This was my first post, I always used stackoverflow to resolve enquiries, but I just joined this community, happy to see how helpful all of you are.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to came up with an answer myself and it works just fine.

```js
function newsSnippets() {
    let classNewsarticle = document.getElementsByClassName("newsarticle");  // Get classes by name 'newsarticle'
    let headlinesId = document.getElementById("headlines");                 // Get Id 'headlines'
    let newsSummary = document.createElement("div");                        // Create DIV
    headlinesId.appendChild(newsSummary);                                   // Append headlines to DIV
    let newsSummaryList = document.createElement("ul");                     // Create UL
    newsSummary.appendChild(newsSummaryList);                               // Append UL to DIV
    
    for (let i = 0; i < classNewsarticle.length; i++) {
        let newsSummaryListItem = document.createElement("LI");             // Create an LI for each H4
        newsSummaryList.appendChild(newsSummaryListItem);                   // Append the LI to the UL
        let getH4 = document.getElementsByTagName("H4")[i];                 // Get H4s
        let getH4Text = getH4.childNodes[0].nodeValue;                      // Get H4s Nodes
        let getH4Node = document.createTextNode(getH4Text);                 // Get H4s HTML Text
        let ellipsis = document.createTextNode(" . . . ");                  // Create Text Node Ellipsis
        let p = getH4.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;                         // Get P as the Next Element Sibling from each H4
        let pText = document.createTextNode(p);                             // Create Text Node for each first P after H4
        newsSummaryListItem.appendChild(getH4Node) +                        // Append the textNodes to the LI element
        newsSummaryListItem.appendChild(ellipsis) +
        newsSummaryListItem.appendChild(pText);
        }
    }
window.onload = newsSnippets;
```